# coverage runs very slowly on windows with python 3.8, but not 3.7

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu

I have a flask based app, when I run coverage on the pytests in windows using python 3.8 it runs very slowly. It performs much better in python 3.7. The following are the test completion times using a the same laptop, the Ubuntu times are the same machine running as a VM.

```
python 3.8.2 - Windows 10 - coverage - **199** seconds
python 3.8.2 - Windows 10 - pytest - 15 seconds
python 3.8.2 - Ubuntu - coverage -  26 seconds
python 3.8.2 - Ubuntu - pytest - 15 seconds
python 3.7.5 - Windows 10 - coverage - **30** seconds
python 3.7.5 - Windows 10 - pytest - 15 seconds
python 3.7.5 - Ubuntu - coverage -  26 seconds
python 3.7.5 - Ubuntu - pytest - 15 seconds
```

Does anyone have any idea why 3.8 on windows running coverage is so slow?

Comment: What Python distribution are you using on Windows?

Comment: I used the msi available from https://www.python.org/downloads for windows and for ubuntu it was built from source.

Answer (score 3):

The cause is that with python 3.8 coverage is installing without C extensions, but with 3.7 it is installing with c extensions.

Now I need to find out why this is the case.

Comment: Did you eventually find out what the reason was? Which version of coverage are you on - and does it have wheels? In my case, I used [coverage=4.5.4](https://pypi.org/project/coverage/4.5.4/#files) which only had macos wheel for 3.8 and 3.7 for other platforms  